# Android 5.0 (API 21) UnknownHostException:

Tags: android, android-networking, android-4.1-jelly-bean

I am getting these error logs when the API is called from any device running Android 5 (API 21). Not sure if it's related to the networking library or any legacy issue with Android version 5 and below.

Log:

```
Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter 
androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
2022-10-19 10:23:48.519 4653-4716/com.app E/Mint: NetSender: Transmitting Exception Unable to resolve host "f78bc3d7.api.splkmobile.com": No address associated with hostname
2022-10-19 10:23:48.519 4653-4716/com.app W/System.err: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "f78bc3d7.api.splkmobile.com": No address associated with hostname
2022-10-19 10:23:48.519 4653-4716/com.app W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:457)
2022-10-19 10:23:48.519 4653-4716/com.app W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
2022-10-19 10:23:48.519 4653-4716/com.app W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
2022-10-19 10:23:48.519 4653-4716/com.app W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.HostResolver$1.getAllByName(HostResolver.java:29)
2022-10-19 10:23:48.519 4653-4716/com.app W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:232)
2022-10-19 10:23:48.519 4653-4716/com.app W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:124)
2022-10-19 10:23:48.519 4653-4716/com.app W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:272)
2022-10-19 10:23:48.519 4653-4716/com.app W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
2022-10-19 10:23:48.519 4653-4716/com.app W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:373)
2022-10-19 10:23:48.519 4653-4716/com.app W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:106)
2022-10-19 10:23:48.519 4653-4716/com.app W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:208)
2022-10-19 10:23:48.520 4653-4716/com.app W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:218)
2022-10-19 10:23:48.520 4653-4716/com.app W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
2022-10-19 10:23:48.520 4653-4716/com.app W/System.err:     at com.splunk.mint.NetSender.sendBlocking(NetSender.java:99)
2022-10-19 10:23:48.520 4653-4716/com.app W/System.err:     at com.splunk.mint.ActionEvent.send(ActionEvent.java:101)
2022-10-19 10:23:48.520 4653-4716/com.app W/System.err:     at com.splunk.mint.Mint$2.run(Mint.java:189)
2022-10-19 10:23:48.520 4653-4716/com.app W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
2022-10-19 10:23:48.520 4653-4716/com.app W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.GaiException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
2022-10-19 10:23:48.520 4653-4716/com.app W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.android_getaddrinfo(Native Method)
2022-10-19 10:23:48.520 4653-4716/com.app W/System.err:     at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.android_getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:55)
2022-10-19 10:23:48.520 4653-4716/com.app W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:438)
```

- Some more logs:

  ```
    java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host 
    "f78bc3d7.api.splkmobile.com": No address associated with hostname
    2022-10-20 08:50:16.207 4711-4774/com.ap W/System.err: at 
    java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:457)
    2022-10-20 08:50:16.207 4711-4774/com.ap W/System.err: at 
    java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
    2022-10-20 08:50:16.207 4711-4774/com.ap W/System.err: at 
    java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
    2022-10-20 08:50:16.207 4711-4774/com.ap W/System.err: at com.android.okhttp.HostResolver$1.getAllByName(HostResolver.java:29)
    2022-10-20 08:50:16.207 4711-4774/com.ap W/System.err: at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:232)
  ```

The log suggests that there is something to do with either Graphics or Network call.

Comment: You mean Android API 21? As there's no Android 21 released yet... Android API 21 if I remember correctly is somewhere around the Android 4~5 ?

Comment: @DanBaruch Hey Dan, my bad, yes i was referring to Android 5 (API 21)

Answer (score 0):

There's no `f78bc3d7.api.splkmobile.com` host. Probably you've made a typo or were given a wrong address.

```
% ping f78bc3d7.api.splkmobile.com
ping: cannot resolve f78bc3d7.api.splkmobile.com: Unknown host
```

Comment: Im not sure, seems like its being called internally.

Comment: Based on stack trace, you're using Splunk MINT, which is not available anymore. 
"Splunk MINT is no longer available for purchase as of January 29, 2021. Customers who have already been paying to ingest and process MINT data in Splunk Enterprise will continue to receive support until December 31, 2021, which is End of Life for all MINT products: App, Web Service (Management Console), SDK and Add-On." May be you're using some old libraries. What are you trying to do?